# How is the 2's complement number system actually defined?

Tags: digital-logic

In my studies of digital logic, I have seen two "definitions" for the 2's complement representation:

(1) Most books simply define the 2's complement of a number \$A\$ which is within the range which can be represented by the given number \$n\$ of bits as
$$\tilde{A}_2 = \bar{A}+1,$$
where I have used a tilde to denote the 2's complement and the bar denotes bitwise complementing (i.e. 1's complement).

(2) I have rarely seen the 2's complement of \$A\$ defined as the unique \$n\$-bit pattern such that \$A = A_{n-1}\cdots A_1A_0\$ when we use the rule $$A_{n-1}\cdots A_1A_0 \equiv -2^{n-1} A_{n-1} + \dots + 2^1A_1 + 2^0 A_0.$$

Now I *know* that these two definitions are equivalent but I have not ever seen a proof of this and would greatly appreciate if someone could supply it or, perhaps, point me to a (presumably older?) resource which does prove this (and prove, for example, that definition (2) is valid in that there does *exist* a *unique* bit pattern for any number in the range).

Comment: what is the meaning of second equation? and how it is same as the first equation.

Comment: @ImGroot What do you mean by second and first here? I haven't numbered the equations which isn't great but are you referring to the defining equations?

Comment: The first equation in section 1, this is a 2's complement equation but about the other equation in section 2. The reason, as per my understanding, why the this equation is not so common for representing 2's complement is that If we input a binary number, it will give the 2's complement but it will not generate a binary number for sure. And we need to convert the number back to the binary again.

Comment: @EE18 Why haven't you started with [*"Preliminary Discussion of the Logical Design of an Electronic Computing Instrument"*](https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/library/Prelim_Disc_Logical_Design.pdf) by Burks, Goldstine, and von Neumann, 1947, and followed articles between that one and *"Arithmetic Operations in a Binary Computer"* by Robert Shaw, 1950? Shaw's publication, in particular, is helpful here. I always go straight to the primary literature when looking for such answers. Why didn't you? (Google Scholar is helpful.)

Comment: I've just downloaded and will give that a look...I admittedly have never really used Google Scholar that much but will work that into my "flow" before asking here going forward :) @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 You ask ***pointed*** questions that relate directly to ***definitions*** of things. I think that's fine to do. But I also think this places a burden on you before asking such questions, because otherwise you simply open it up to anyone's ***wag*** on the topic rather than the results of hard work by important thinkers who have already addressed these questions and were the ones ***creating*** the definitions you ask for. I would expect you to track those down, first, and set the tone for your question based upon a recognition of that prior solid foundation to save everyone time.

Comment: @EE18 I wouldn't be surprised to find that Alan Turing and/or Alonzo Church, in the 1930's, also addressed this question. But I didn't track things back that far for you. But you should do that, just to make sure it doesn't go back that far or still further. You find good references, see the references they cite, then go get those references and read them and if you see still earlier references there that may be important, you go track those down, as well. All the way back! It's basic research methodology. When looking for precise definitions, look to the experts first. Not us here. ;)

Comment: @EE18 Many definitions are arbitrarily made. For example, we arbitrarily defined the meaning of `planet` centuries ago when we were very, very **ignorant** about the physics of stellar nurseries, star formation, and so on. It wasn't until some very important papers arrived showing ***natural*** demarcations, that we changed those definitions and excluded Pluto, for example. (That demarcation that nature showed us was a natural gap ***wider than 5 orders of magnitude***, so it was quite clear in the data.)

Comment: @EE18  So. When looking for good definitions? Ask the best minds. Otherwise you just get arbitrary ones, like you will get to "what's a capital gains tax?" (Which is just about as arbitrary as arbitrary can get.)

Comment: The definition is not arbitrary. The question in the title is how is the 2's complement defined.  The 2's complement of a number A respect to 2^N is B such that A + B = 2^N.  The other 2 formulas are ways to perform it, can be demostrated (the other answers) that they are equivalent to B = 2^N - A, in binary, with N bits and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm going to kind of meander through this answer because I'm working it out as I go, but it might help to think in terms of modulo arithmetic.

> \$A_{n-1}\cdots A_1A_0 \equiv -2^{n-1} A_{n-1} + \dots + 2^1A_1 + 2^0 A_0.\$

This is just a consequence of the fact that in mod-2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic, \$-2^{n-1}\equiv 2^n\$ (where \$\equiv\$ represents congruence mod-2<sup>n</sup>). You can show this congruence by considering

$$-2^{n-1} + 2^n = -2^{n-1} + 2\times 2^{n-1}$$
so
$$-2^{n-1} + 2^n = 2^{n-1}.$$

> \$\tilde{A}_2 = \bar{A}+1\$

This is true in mod-2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic because

$$A + \bar{A} = 2^{n}-1$$

(since \$2^{n}-1\$ has a bit pattern with all bits set)

Then the additive inverse of A in mod-2<sup>n</sup> must be \$\bar{A}+1\$.

Thinking about it this way, the second formula can be seen as a definition of a particular choice of the numbers in \$\Bbb{N}\$ (the set of integers) that will be chosen for each value in the mod-2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic.

And the first formula is just a straightforward fact about mod-2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic that's true regardless of which integer we interpret each congruence class in the modulo arithmetic to represent.

Comment: I think I understand somewhat better now about the first definition being equivalent to the "true" definition which has been quoted a few other times here, e.g. by Adam Haun. If it's possible I just wanted to follow up with you about the second point which, I now realize, is not really a definition so much as a theorem in a sense. You write " the first formula is just a straightforward fact about mod-2n arithmetic that's true regardless of which integer we interpret each congruence class in the modulo arithmetic to represent"...

Comment: ... Does this mean that when we speak of "2s complement" and interpret positive and negative numbers, what we are really doing is choosing particular members of congruence classes for the bit pattern to represent? It's that connection I think I'm missing. If you have any suggested sources on rigorous digital logic etc. I would also be all ears. Also, at the start, did you mean \$ -2^{n-1}\equiv 2^{n-1} \, (mod \, 2^n)\$ perhaps?

Comment: About "choosing members of congruence classes", yes, I'm saying the computer does mod-2^n arithmetic, and we can interpret the result either as giving values between 0 and 2^n-1, or between -2^(n-1) and 2^(n-1)-1. But I'm not expert on this area and I probably don't have the vocabulary to express it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at it. First, the actual definition of the two's complement of an N-bit number x is:

$$TC(x) = 2^N - x$$

This is, of course, equivalent to your \$\bar{x} + 1\$ definition. Now, in two's complement arithmetic the following things are true:

1. All negative numbers have their most significant bit set.
2. The largest positive number that can be represented is \$2^{N-1} - 1\$.

I'm going to use 4-bit numbers to make this easier to write, but the argument works for any number of bits. Let's say we have a positive number with digits \$B_3B_2B_1B_0\$, which corresponds to a negative two's complement value of \$A_3A_2A_1A_0\$. Using my definition above:

$$TC(B_3B_2B_1B_0) = 2^4 - B_3B_2B_1B_0 = A_3A_2A_1A_0$$

We know that \$B_3 = 0\$ and \$A_3 = 1\$. So:

$$2^4 - B_2B_1B_0 = 2^3 + A_2A_1A_0$$

\$2^3 + 2^3 = 2^4\$, so:

$$-B_2B_1B_0 = -2^3 + A_2A_1A_0$$

If you're satisfied that \$TC(B)\$ is equivalent to \$-B\$, perhaps that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add n+1 bits binary numbers.

Binary encoding :
$$A = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i*2^i$$
Power of twos series : (1+2+4+8 = 15 = 16-1). Can be demonstrated by recurrence.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1$$
Binary inversion can be written as (1-X) for each bit :
$$\bar{A} = \sum_{i=0}^n (1-a_i)*2^i =  \sum_{i=0}^n 2^i - \sum_{i=0}^n a_i*2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1 -  \sum_{i=0}^n a_i*2^i$$

$$B =\bar{A} + 1$$

$$A + B =  \sum_{i=0}^n a_i*2^i + 2^{n+1} - 1 - \sum_{i=0}^n a_i*2^i + 1 $$
$$A + B =  2^{n+1} $$

So, if we add A + (-A), with (-A) defined as /A+1, the result is an overflow bit, which is discarded when the result is truncated to n+1 bits.

(Note that there are other possible representations of numbers, instead of weighting each digit as 0 and 1,  for example +1 and -1 is used for non-restoring division, sometimes each digit is made of two booleans, carry-add, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps I am not following closely enough, but this appears to be a proof that a 2's complement is, indeed, an additive inverse, no?